# How does Bitcoin Core sort memory pool transactions by fee?

Tags: bitcoin-core, transaction-fees, mempool, transaction-selection

I'm trying to understand the algorithm Bitcoin Core uses to sort memory pool transactions by fee.

Gavin's [fee rework proposal](https://gist.github.com/gavinandresen/2961409) states:

> Next, sort all remaining memory pool transactions by fee-paid-per-kilobyte, and include as many as will fit until the block is maximum block size bytes big, not including "free" transactions (transactions with fee-per-kb of less than the default spam threshold of 0.0001 BTC/kilobyte).

This makes sense, because a miner should want to load a block with transactions carrying the most "fee density", or fee per byte.

However, reviewing the [CreateNewBlock function in miner.cpp](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/v0.10.2/src/miner.cpp#L258), it's not clear how Bitcoin Core accounts for transaction length when prioritizing memory pool items:

```
// Prioritise by fee once past the priority size or we run out of high-priority
// transactions:
if (!fSortedByFee &&
    ((nBlockSize + nTxSize >= nBlockPrioritySize) || !AllowFree(dPriority)))
{
    fSortedByFee = true;
    comparer = TxPriorityCompare(fSortedByFee);
    std::make_heap(vecPriority.begin(), vecPriority.end(), comparer);
}
```

TXPriorityCompare seems to just look at absolute fee:

```
public:
    TxPriorityCompare(bool _byFee) : byFee(_byFee) { }

    bool operator()(const TxPriority& a, const TxPriority& b)
    {
        if (byFee)
        {
            if (a.get<1>() == b.get<1>())
                return a.get<0>() < b.get<0>();
            return a.get<1>() < b.get<1>();
        }
        else
        {
            if (a.get<0>() == b.get<0>())
                return a.get<1>() < b.get<1>();
            return a.get<0>() < b.get<0>();
        }
    }
};
```

In other words, this looks like a sort on absolute transaction fee, not fee density. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

The excerpt you're showing is for the priority area in blocks. The concept of "priority" in the source code corresponds modified bitcoin-days-destroyed per kilobyte. It is only used for a small portion of the block size (max 50kB by default in Bitcoin Core 0.11.x, and max 0kB by default in 0.12.x, it can be changed with a configuration setting).

Look at the rest of CreateNewBlock, which uses sorting by feerate, by iterating an index on the mempool that is pre-sorted by feerate (=satoshi per kB).